# How to configure TestNG to run just a single test case in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng, testng.xml

I have two separate packages in my project, one for integration tests and one for unit tests, my testng.xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="All test cases" verbose="1" parallel="classes">
    <test name="Integration Tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.sample.integration.ClassC"/>
            <class name="com.sample.integration.ClassD"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Unit tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.sample.unit.ClassA"/>
            <class name="com.sample.unit.ClassB"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Class C:

```
public class ClassC {

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeIntegrationTests() {
        System.out.println("Before Integration tests");
    }

    @Test
    public void classCMethod() {
        System.out.println("Executing class C method");
    }
}
```

Class D:

```
public class ClassD {

    @Test
    public void classDMethod() {
        System.out.println("Executing class D method");
    }
}
```

Class A:

```
public class ClassA {

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeUnitTests() {
        System.out.println("Before unit tests");
    }

    @Test
    public void classAMethod() {
        System.out.println("Executing class A method");
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class ClassB {
    @Test
    public void classBMethod() {
        System.out.println("Executing class B method");
    }
}
```

If I run the entire test suite it works as expected as follows:

```
Before Integration tests
Executing class C method
Executing class D method
Before unit tests
Executing class A method
Executing class B method
```

However, if I try to either run/debug just `classAMethod()` from `ClassA`, it runs `beforeUnitTests()` [*expected*] and `classAMethod()` [*expected*], however it also runs `beforeIntegrationTests()` which is **not expected**. As per the [official documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html): `@BeforeTest`: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the `<test>` tag is run.
How do I configure **TestNG** and/or **IntelliJ** to run this correctly?

**Side Note:** Although I can see that the `beforeIntegrationTests()` is getting run either by adding a breakpoint in the debug mode or by adding a `Thread.sleep` in the run mode, the output from this method does not get printed in final console output.

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the run configuration created for you when you run classAMethod() in ClassA? The issue is not reproduced for me with IntelliJ IDEA v2020.1.1, can you please check if the issue is experienced with this version for you as well (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406674/how-to-run-a-single-test-case-method-instead-of-whole-test-suite-class-using/62411625?noredirect=1#comment110400049_62411625 Please check this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly, is the expectation valid, as in I expect only beforeUnitTests() and classAMethod() to run if I run just the classAMethod().
```

No, all methods with `@BeforeTest` annotation will run before execution of method with `@Test` annotation.

Ideal way to handle this scenario is with `groups`.

Class A:

```
public class ClassA {

    @BeforeTest(groups="unitTest")
    public void beforeUnitTests() {
        System.out.println("Before unit tests");
    }

    @Test(groups="unitTest")
    public void classAMethod() {
        System.out.println("Executing class A method");
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class ClassB {
    @Test(groups="unitTest")
    public void classBMethod() {
        System.out.println("Executing class B method");
    }
}
```

Class C:

```
public class ClassC {

    @BeforeTest(groups="integrationTest")
    public void beforeIntegrationTests() {
        System.out.println("Before Integration tests");
    }

    @Test(groups="integrationTest")
    public void classCMethod() {
        System.out.println("Executing class C method");
    }
}
```

Class D:

```
public class ClassD {

    @Test(groups="integrationTest")
    public void classDMethod() {
        System.out.println("Executing class D method");
    }
}
```

testNG XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="All test cases" verbose="1" parallel="classes">
<groups>
<run>
<include name="unitTest"></include>
</run>
</groups>
    <test name="Test Suite">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.sample.integration.ClassC"/>
            <class name="com.sample.integration.ClassD"/>
            <class name="com.sample.unit.ClassA"/>
            <class name="com.sample.unit.ClassB"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

You can make further configuration to this testNg XML as per your needs.

Comment: I guess the expectation is valid as per official documentation: @BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the <test> tag is run.
https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406674/how-to-run-a-single-test-case-method-instead-of-whole-test-suite-class-using/62411625?noredirect=1#comment110400049_62411625